# How do I correctly use map & zip to compare properties in my array of Structs?

Tags: swift, dictionary, boolean, zip

I am using the following line to compare the correctAnswers in a quiz to the answers that the user submitted.

It returns an array of bools, which I would then search through and count how many true and how many false they got (true = correct and false = incorrect).

```
let totalResults = map(zip(correctAnswers, userAnswers)){$0.0 == $0.1}
```

I have all my quiz information stored in an array of structs e.g 
struct questionInfo {

```
    var question : String!
    var answer : Bool!
    var userAnswer : Bool!
    var explanation : String!


    init(question: String, answer: Bool, explanation: String!) {
        self.question = question
        self.answer = answer
        self.explanation = explanation
    }
}


// These are the questions that will be shuffled before the quiz begins
var quizQuestion =

 [
    questionInfo(question: "Question 0", answer: true, explanation: ""),
    questionInfo(question: "Question 1", answer: true, explanation: ""),
    questionInfo(question: "Question 2", answer: true, explanation: ""),
    questionInfo(question: "Question 3", answer: true, explanation: ""),
    questionInfo(question: "Question 4", answer: true, explanation: "")
                                                                        ]
```

How would I input the info from the array of structs into my map & zip line. I tried appending all the answers to an array using a for loop but it seems very messy.

For clarification I want to do something like this:

```
let totalResults = map(zip(quizQuestion[x].answer, quizQuestion[x].userAnswer)){$0.0 == $0.1}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `zip()` if all information is in the single `quizQuestion`
array, only `map()`:

```
let totalResults = map(quizQuestion) { $0.answer == $0.userAnswer }   // [Bool]
```

Then you can count the number of correct answers with `reduce()`:

```
let numberOfCorrectResults = reduce(totalResults, 0) { $0 + Int($1) } // Int
```

This is the Swift 1.2 syntax, for Swift 2 from Xcode 7 beta it would be

```
let totalResults = quizQuestion.map { $0.answer == $0.userAnswer }   // [Bool]
let numberOfCorrectResults = totalResults.reduce(0) { $0 + Int($1) } // Int
```

Comment: Great answers - Thank you!